# Get id from a one div to another div

Tags: jquery

Here are the two divs

```
<div id="1">

<span id="a1">first</span>
<span id="a2b">first</span>
<span id="a3">first</span>

</div>
```

Click

```
<div id=2></div>
```

And the jQuery code to do

```
  $('#2').bind('click',function(){
            var xx = $('#a'+i).attr('id');
            $('#2').append(xx);
            i=i+1;
        });
```

It does not get all the 3 id's from #1

Thanks
Jean

Comment: first of all, you shouldn't start your id's with an integer. other than that, you haven't described very well what you want to do, and how that differs from what you've achieved right now.

Comment: @david please let go off the small bits, focus on the answer, I altered the code for stackoverflow

Comment: Most of your questions are unclear, and you are very spiteful to those *trying to help* in **every** question you ask, no one wants users like that in the community.  Either learn how to accept help, or please stop asking questions.

Comment: @nick considering this question: **My question is how do I get the ids of the spans in one div so that I can append it to the next div**.  
I have provided all relevant code which I am using, and not achieving the same.

What I want to do is irrelevant, the question is can anyone provide an answer.

Comment: @nick, read the next comment to the said comment

Answer (score 1):

First of all, element IDs should start with a letter or the underscore character. Second of all, try this:

```
$("#second").click(function() {

    // grab the ids of the first div's spans into an array
    var ids = $("#first span").map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get();
    alert(ids);

    $(this).append(ids.join(",")); // or whatever
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: @karim79 please let go off the small bits, focus on helping me out with the answer, I altered the code for stackoverflow

Comment: If you look carefully, you'll see that the above example grabs the three IDs from the elements in the first div, and stores them in the variable `ids`.

Answer (score 0):

In your click function, variable 'i' is used before being set and this may explain your problems.

Can you check if initializing the variable helps?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
 $('#2').bind('click',function(){
       var dest = $(this);
       $("#1").find("span").each(function(){
           dest.append($(this).attr('id'));
       });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell exactly what you want, but couldn't you do this to move all of the elements:

```
$("#1").children().appendTo("#2")
```